# Pegar colunas específicas com Laravel querybuilder

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Considere que minha tabela no DB tenha muitas colunas. Porém, pra uma consulta específica eu não preciso de todas elas.
 Como eu faria no Laravel ( usando tanto o Eloquent quanto o QueryBuilder para pegar apenas as colunas que preciso?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para definir as colunas que deseja selecionar utilize *select*:

```
DB::table('nome_da_tabela')->select('coluna1', 'coluna2')->get();
```

Conforme encontra na [documentação](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#selects).

Comment: Defina descricao_da_coluna? "nome, idade, email" por exemplo.

Comment: Isso ai! DB::table('users')->select('name','email')->get();

Comment: Alguma ideia de como ficaria usando o Eloquent?

Comment: @CesardeBarros da mesma forma... *User::select('name','email')->get();*

Answer (score -1):

Reforçando, existem outras diversas formas de se fazer isso. Citarei dois exemplos:

```
DB::table('nome_da_tabela')->get(['coluna1', 'coluna2']);
```

Ou com eloquent:

```
Model::get(['coluna1', 'coluna2']);
```